# не открывается модальное изображение

Tags: javascript, html, css

Прошу подать руку помощи.
Начинаю вливаться в разработку сайтов и практикуюсь созданием сайтов.
Создаю сайт отеля, решил сделать несколько модальных изображений, с изображением якобы номеров.
На сайте HTML5CSS нашёл пример как сделать, - сделал первое изображение. Сработало, при попытке создать второе изображение оно не работает, первое открывается все хорошо, второе на клик не реагирует, ведёт себя как обычное изображение.

```js
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

var img = document.getElementById('myImg');
var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
img.onclick = function(){
    modal.style.display = "block";
    modalImg.src = this.src;
    captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
}

var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}
 var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

var img = document.getElementById('myImg');
var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
img.onclick = function(){
    modal.style.display = "block";
    modalImg.src = this.src;
    captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
}

var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
#myImg {
    border-radius: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

#myImg:hover {opacity: 0.7;}

/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.9); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content (image) */
.modal-content {
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    width: 80%;
    max-width: 700px;
}

/* Caption of Modal Image */
#caption {
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    width: 80%;
    max-width: 700px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #ccc;
    padding: 10px 0;
    height: 150px;
}

/* Add Animation */
.modal-content, #caption {    
    -webkit-animation-name: zoom;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.6s;
    animation-name: zoom;
    animation-duration: 0.6s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes zoom {
    from {-webkit-transform:scale(0)} 
    to {-webkit-transform:scale(1)}
}

@keyframes zoom {
    from {transform:scale(0)} 
    to {transform:scale(1)}
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
    position: absolute;
    top: 15px;
    right: 35px;
    color: #f1f1f1;
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: bold;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
    color: #bbb;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

/* 100% Image Width on Smaller Screens */
@media only screen and (max-width: 700px){
    .modal-content {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

```html
<img id="myImg" src="standart.jpg" alt="Standart" style="width:100%;max-width:300px">

<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <span class="close">×</span>
  <img class="modal-content" id="img01">
  <div id="caption"></div>
</div>
        <br>
        <img id="myImg" src="juniorsuite.jpg" alt="Junior Suite" style="width:100%;max-width:300px">

<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <span class="close">×</span>
  <img class="modal-content" id="img01">
  <div id="caption"></div>
</div>
```

Помогите, в упор смотрю и не понимаю, что не так. Надеюсь на понимание и помощь...

Comment: Как минимум id - уникальный идентификатор, не должно быть 2 элемента с одинаковым id

Comment: да собственно у вас код что делает? 2 раза ищет:

var img = document.getElementById('myImg');
и в обоих случаях навешивает onclick на один и тот же img

Comment: оберните каждый (img и <div class="modal">) в еще один div контейнер (получится 2 div контейнера) и ищите уже по классу. Нашли картинку по классу - и дальше ищем в том же контейнере div modal и его и показываем

Answer (score 1):

Внимание! я подсказал как делать - в комментарии!!

здесь ответ.

```js
const images = document.querySelectorAll('.modal-image');

images.forEach(image => {
  const modalContainer = image.parentNode;
  const modal = modalContainer.querySelector('.modal');
  const caption = modalContainer.querySelector('.caption');
  
  image.onclick = function(event) {
    modal.style.display = "block";
    caption.innerHTML = event.target.alt;
  }
  
  const closeSpan = modalContainer.querySelector('.close');
  
  closeSpan.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
});
```

```css
#myImg {
    border-radius: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

#myImg:hover {opacity: 0.7;}

/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: yellow; /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content (image) */
.modal-content {
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    width: 80%;
    max-width: 700px;
}

/* Caption of Modal Image */
#caption {
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    width: 80%;
    max-width: 700px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #ccc;
    padding: 10px 0;
    height: 150px;
}

/* Add Animation */
.modal-content, #caption {    
    -webkit-animation-name: zoom;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.6s;
    animation-name: zoom;
    animation-duration: 0.6s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes zoom {
    from {-webkit-transform:scale(0)} 
    to {-webkit-transform:scale(1)}
}

@keyframes zoom {
    from {transform:scale(0)} 
    to {transform:scale(1)}
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
    position: absolute;
    top: 15px;
    right: 35px;
    color: black;
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: bold;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
    color: #bbb;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

/* 100% Image Width on Smaller Screens */
@media only screen and (max-width: 700px){
    .modal-content {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="modal-container">
  <img class="modal-image" src="https://4football.com.ua/imgs/m8954.jpg" alt="Standart" width="100" height="100">

  <div class="modal">
    <span class="close">×</span>
    <img class="modal-content" id="img01">
    <div class="caption"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="modal-container">
  <img class="modal-image" src="https://assetmanagerpim-res.cloudinary.com/images/w_600/q_90/e05c644cb91b42dc8019ad1101593139_9366/GT7788_01_standard.WebP" alt="Junior Suite" width="100" height="100">

  <div class="modal">
    <span class="close">×</span>
    <img class="modal-content" id="img01">
    <div class="caption"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```